# Wordpress Visual Composer container inside stretch_row_content

Tags: css, wordpress, visual-composer

I have a row that is stretch_row_content and has a background color, what I am trying to do is add a container inside this row, I looked at all the settings and I don't see anywhere to do so, the container class I am trying to add is .content_wrapper Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my row:

```
[vc_row full_width="stretch_row_content" css=".vc_custom_1486004355595{margin-top: -20px !important;}"][/vc_row]
```

Comment: Why aren't you adding it with Visual Composer instead of directly in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:
1. Pick a row element and make it full width.
2. Inside This row element you can take another row element which will act like a container of the row.

The resulted output Will be:

```
[vc_row fullwidth="true" equal_columns="true" attached="true" css=".vc_custom_1488750249007{background-color: #dd3333 !important;}"][vc_column][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

[Click to see the output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm735.png)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There is an option in Row setting which makes the row as a container.